# Do professors think that teaching undergraduates is a waste of their time?

Tags: teaching, undergraduate

I am confused as to why highly intelligent professors would want to teach undergraduate students. It sounds to me like a lifetime of toil.

Do professors find the time spent teaching undergraduates a waste of time?

Comment: No, of course not.

Comment: Of course it is well known that many look down on grading.

Comment: I think you can conclude from the content of your own post that many intelligent people believe teaching is worthwhile.  People who think teaching is a waste of time probably don't know how learning works or how it helps students.  The "helps students" part, at least, is obvious to academics.  And probably too broad to make into a single answer.

Comment: Is trolling a waste of time?

Comment: I edited the text a bit to make it less trollish.

Comment: The answer is an emphatic No!

Comment: The only time teaching undergraduates is a waste of time is when the undergraduates think that learning is a waste of time.

Answer (score 3):

I can only speak for myself with certainty, but I think most people who become professors are partly motivated by altruistic reasons.  We become professors because we want to help other people, and for most of us, we think that all people in society, not only an intellectual elect, are made in the image of God(*) and ought to be helped.

Of course I often find teaching difficult, frustrating, annoying, and so on (though rarely boring), but I also get the satisfaction of doing good in the world.

(*) substitute your favorite deity or cosmic principle

Comment: Some weirdos like me also find it fun (aside from hopefully making the world a better place, etc.)